# Why do I get different PDF FlateDecode formats?

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to read a bunch of PDFs and just pull out the text. For half of my sample text that uses FlateDecode I just use `gzuncompress`, and I get back something I can parse to grab the text:

```
Tw [(remains an unresolved theoretical and pragmatic conundr)]
```

But other times after `gzuncompress()` I get back something like:

```
TD [(\002\016\032)-233.5 (\017\004\t/+\013\r\016\013\004\024\f)-233.5 
    (\b\002\017\004\032)-233.5 (\004;\024\t\002\016\002\f\n\r\016\017)-233.4
    (\r/)-233.5 (\013\022\002\023\n\017 \002\f\n\013)-233.4
    (\t\004\002\032\004\023\017\022\n\024)-233.5 (1\004\020\003\020\033)-233.5
    (\001\022\002 \n\023)]TJ
```

I am pretty sure this is text as I can't get any other text from the PDF and it is inside a `BT ... ET`

What is this second format and how can I convert it to something readable?

Comment: check the [reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) first line is ascii text without encoding table in the pdf file body. second line is octal numbers -- addresses of letters in encoding section.

Comment: The Section 5.9 (Extraction of Text Content) describes _Differences_ array and _ToUnicode_ CMap.

Comment: @RubenKazumov You might want to make this an answer for Justin to accept.

Comment: Please use one of the many pdf libraries available.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find CMap for font descriptor for each line of the textual data in file. It will look like:

```
16 0 obj 
    << /Length 433 >>
    stream 
    /CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin 
    12 dict begin b
    egincmap 
    /CIDSystemInfo 
    << /Registry (Adobe) 
    /Ordering (UCS) 
    /Supplement 0 
    >> def 
    /CMapName /Adobe−Identity−UCS def 
    /CMapType 2 def 
    1 begincodespacerange 
    <0000> <FFFF> 
    endcodespacerange 
    2 beginbfrange 
    <0000> <005E> <0020> 
    <005F> <0061> [<00660066> <00660069> <00660066006C>] 
    endbfrange 
    1 beginbfchar 
    <3A51> <D840DC3E> 
    endbfchar 
    endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end endstream 
endobj
```

Lets convert this example in table form:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+
| write hex | or ascii | or octal |  with substitution   | and will see |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+
| <5f>      | _        | \137     | U+0066 U+0066        | ff           |
| <60>      | `        | \140     | U+0066 U+0069        | fi           |
| <61>      | a        | \141     | U+0066 U+0066 U+006c | ffl          |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+
```

Therefore, if you will see the text under font descriptor with current CMap:

```
TD[(\137\140\141)]TJ === fffiffl
```

This example CMap consists one more substitution. For single character:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------------+
| write hex | or octal | means in UTF-16BE  | and Unicode |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------------+
| <3a51>    | \35121   | <D840DC3E>         | U+2003e     |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------------+
```

And this substitution is `TD[(\35121)]TJ ===` 𠀾

*References:*

[PDF Reference six edition Adobe Portable Document Format version 1.7, November 2006](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)

Comment: PDF is not for meaning. It's for representation of meaning.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your text showing example is for simple (single byte encoding) font, while this ToUnicode CMap (example copied from Reference) is for double byte codes and composite font. And since ToUnicode resources are different for different fonts (especially subsets, as in OP's example), located in different places throughout the file, linked to in font dictionaries (indirect objects), -- the way OP seeks to extract text (manually, as it looks) may be anything from very difficult to impossible.

Comment: Good answer! But it's worth mentioning that also ranges in `beginbfrange` map to `UTF-16BE` strings, not only `beginbfchar` mappings. This is better specified in PdfReference 1.7 page 472 and clarifies example 5.16 at page 473. Without this clarification, explanation of example 5.16 (page 474) seems to suggest only `beginbfchar` is a mapping to a `UTF-16BE` string.  Also Technical Note [#5411](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/5411.ToUnicode.pdf) confirms this at page 5.